# How do "middleware frameworks" score for modularity?

Tags: node.js, modularity

Lately I've been learning a lot about node.js and the surrounding library ecosystem. Some of the libraries I've come across have been what's been called "middleware" frameworks. These are libraries like [Connect.js](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/) and [Flatiron](http://flatironjs.org/).

I'm wondering if middleware is a reasonable form of modularity, pros and cons, and comparison to built-in structures for modularity: functions and objects.

I came across [this interesting question (and answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5683916/node-js-express-vs-geddy), which gives the opinion that one probably shouldn't use these kinds of middleware frameworks. Is it because they aren't robust forms of modularity?

Comment: Connect is not a framework, it is a thin wrapper over the native nodejs httpserver. Flatiron is dead. Middleware are not the problem. People writting code tied to a peculiar middleware architecture are the problem. But you cant put the blame on the "frameworks" themself.

Comment: The first sentence on Connect's website is "Connect is a middleware framework for node": http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/